# Enabling Windows Mixed Reality on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-mixed-reality

Trying to get Windows Mixed Reality working on Windows Server 2019, I can't seem to get my device to be recognised - I know the creators update was needed for it to kick in, but I'm struggling to find a solution other than 'update' - Nothing specific to 2019

Are there any k updates or repo's that can enable WMR on Windows Server 2019 v1809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2019 is not on the Windows Mixed Reality support list right now. As a prerequisite for MR development, you must be running the Windows 10 Version 1903 or newer to use Windows Mixed Reality, more information please see [this “before you start” page for Windows Mixed Reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/enthusiast-guide/before-you-start#make-sure-you-have-the-windows-10-version-1709-or-newer-installed).

Comment: Ok, so there is no way of implementing just that feature into server2019 - This is all I needed to know. Thanks Hernando!